# NVD3 Library - Line and Bar Chart - Bar chart doesn't load until window resize

Tags: javascript, css, charts, nvd3.js

I'm trying to create a line and bar chart using the NVD3 javascript library. I have an interesting problem where the lines load perfectly fine, but the bars are omitted on initial page load. But, once I resize the window or do an inspect element n the chart, the bar chart loads.

Here is my code:

```
// raw @timeline is just JSON
// This is a rails app
var timeline = <%=raw @timeline %> 
  var chart_concurrent_users_data = [
    {
      values: timeline.map(function(d) { return {x: d[0], y: d[1] } }),
      key: 'Concurrent Users',
      color: '#C0C0C0',
      yAxis: 2,
      bar: true
    },
    {
      values: timeline.map(function(d) { return {x: d[0], y: d[2] } }),
      key: 'User Joins',
      color: '#5cb85c',
      yAxis: 1
    },
    {
      values: timeline.map(function(d) { return {x: d[0], y: d[3] } }),
      key: 'User Leaves',
      color: '#006699',
      yAxis: 1
    }
  ];
  // User Chart / Leave / Joins
  nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart_users = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
      .margin({top: 30, right: 80, bottom: 50, left: 80})
      .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

    // FULL Graph
    chart_users.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
      return d ? d3.time.format('%H:%M%')(new Date(d)) : '';
    });

    chart_users.xAxis.axisLabel('Time');

    chart_users.y2Axis
      .axisLabel('Users joining / leaving')
      .tickFormat(d3.format(',.'));

    chart_users.y1Axis
      .axisLabel('Concurrent Users')
      .tickFormat(d3.format(',.'));

    chart_users.bars.forceY([0]);

    chart_users.lines.forceY([0]);

    d3.select('#chart_users svg')
        .datum(chart_concurrent_users_data)
        .call(chart_users);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart_users.update);

    return chart_users;
 });
```

I've tested this in both chrome and firefox.

Here are some images of the problem.

On initial load:

[image]

After resize:

[image]

Note I can also resize it back to full screen and the bar chart is still present. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.